# Match values from one list to other on different sheet and copy a single cell GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

need help  over an script that is not working on google app script. I have a sheet1 where colA is a date and colB is an ID. On sheet2 i have same ID but could be at any row (not in order). So, the script should find this ID and copy on col P (sheet2) the date on colA (sheet1).
Here the script that doesn't make nothing. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
function CopyDate() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Name');
  sheetA = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  dataA = sheetA.getRange('A:B').getValues();
  sheetB = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  dataB = sheetB.getRange('A:P').getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (dataA[2][i] == dataB[1][i]) {
      var value = sheetA.getRange(i+1, 1).getValue();
      sheetB.getRange(i+1, 16).setValue(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One more thing: the ID on sheet1 is on col B but on sheet2 on colA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "Sheet1" has Date and ID in the column "A" and "B", respectively.
- "Sheet2" has ID in the column "A".
- You want to copy Date of "Sheet1" to the column "P" of "Sheet2" when IDs of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are the same.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- About `for(var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++){`, in this case, the for loop is not used, because of `i > sheetA.getLastRow()`.
- `dataA` and `dataB` are 2 dimentional array like `[[columnA of row1, columnB of row1],[columnA of row2, columnB of row2],,,]`. So at `dataA[2][i] == dataB[1][i]`, the row 2 of "Sheet1" and row 1 of "Sheet2" are compared.
- When `setValue()` is used in a loop, the cost become very high. So please put the values using `setValues()` after created the putting value.
- In your case, when `var dataA = sheetA.getRange(1, 1, sheetA.getLastRow(), 2).getValues()` instead of `sheetA.getRange('A:B').getValues()` is used, the process cost can be reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function CopyDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Name'); // If you want to use openById(), please replace the Spreadsheet ID to ``Name``.
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataA = sheetA.getRange(1, 1, sheetA.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dataB = sheetB.getRange(1, 1, sheetB.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var values = dataB.map(function(e) {
    var t = dataA.filter(function(f) {return f[1] == e[0]});
    return t.length > 0 ? [t[0][0]] : [""];
  });
  sheetB.getRange(1, 16, values.length, 1).setValues(values); // 16 means the column "P".
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `Name` can be seen in `ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById( 'Name');`. If you are using the spreadsheet name, please use the spreadsheet ID. If I misunderstood this, please ignore.
- If you don't want to reduce the process cost, I apologize.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information from it. By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you very match for take your time! It works as i needed. I will study these fuction you reference...i'm learning ths to move wrom VBA. Best wishes , Marina

Comment: If is not too complicate would like to understand map function. I take a look and understand what it does but not too much how, also the line:  return t.length > 0 ? [t[0][0]] : [""]; ...the "?" what it mean.....any way the most import is that it work...this clarification is only to learn...thnak you again

Comment: @MarinaMontero Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. ``return t.length > 0 ? [t[0][0]] : [""]; ...the "?"`` is the same with ``if (t.length > 0) {return [t[0][0]];} else {return [""];}``. It is called [the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Cost of ternary operator is lower than that of "if". [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cef47530a58f2d8692cdb1a9d257907b) About ``map()``, you can see samples at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Tanaike hello, have an small problem ...i need if no data match it hold the last data on sheetB col16, so i modify this line  " return t.length > 0 ? [t[0][0]] : [e[16]];" and add e[16] instead of "" that empty the cell.....but it write "undefined" and the problem is with the format as if i change 16 for 0 it bring me data...the format is a date hour  like 2/12/2019 10:45:33. Any idea how to fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: ...i tried with e[16].toISOString()...but doen't accept

Comment: Solved was the getRange, have to extend the columns. THK You anyway

Comment: Hi Tanike!, how can i do to avoid if not data is found,, doesn't delete the last data. I have tried with the followed statement but it says "t is not defined".

Comment: if (t.length != ''){
    sheetB.getRange(2, 17, values.length, 1).setValues(values)}; // 16 means the column "P".
}

Comment: @MarinaMontero Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your new issue. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. Also I would like to confirm about it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.